# IntelliJ IDEA - multiple carets?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Sometimes I have to write Java class where I need to define multiple fields of the same type. For example, I know that I will need to duplicate `private final String` on the next 4 lines.

Is it possible to spawn **multiple carets** in IntelliJ editor, so I can type on mutliple lines at the sime time?

Comment: Ctrl-D duplicates the current line.

Comment: for multiple carets support please vote for [this ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80056)

Comment: What you say is "Clone caret up/down" in IntelliJ. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think "Column Selection Mode" could help you. You can enable it in the context menu in the editor. Then you can select multiple lines and type same text at once.

Comment: Solves pretty much what I wanted.

Comment: The shortcut to activate "Column Selection Mode" in mac is `shift + cmd + 8`

Answer (score 19):

**IntelliJ IDEA 14.1 & 15**

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and using the **mouse left click** you can put many carets.

E.g.:

[image: long caret 1]

will become

[image: long caret 2]

typing "added" only once.

If you want to have a **continuous vertical line**, it's enough to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + **drag your mouse vertically**. If there are lines with a length lower than the current position, the vertical line will be broken (carets will be placed at the end of every line) if "Allow placement of caret after end of line" is disabled (in File > Settings... > Editor > General > Virtual Space).

Another way to add a **continuous vertical line** is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> twice and then press up or down arrow key (supported in JetBrains 2016.X products, and possibly earlier).

If you cannot get the shortcuts working, check what they're currently assigned to under `Settings > Keymap` `Add or Remove Caret`, `Clone Caret Above` and `Clone Caret Below`. If they look right and you're on Linux, your window manager may be capturing the combination, e.g., for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + window drag operations.

**See**:

- http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/02/multiple-selections-in-editor-using-mouse/
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/multicursor.html

Answer (score 6):

#### Column Select

For Windows, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>(Hold)+<kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>. For Mac, replace the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> with <kbd>⌘</kbd>.

#### Change Multi-caret Hotkey

To add a custom Keymap, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, type `keymap` and click on the one with `Settings` as subtext. Search for `Clone Caret Above` and `Clone Caret Below`.

I mapped mine to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>.

#### Bonus

Try holding combinations of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and arrows for improved selection power.

Comment: I wish one day I woud find the answer Fro Windows, For Mac and for Linux .... cause many guys are now developing under linux versions of IntelliJ products.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows:

- You can enable the Column Selection Mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>)
- And then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd> can select multiple columns
- Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go back to single cursor

Comment: thanks, i pressed alt shift insert by accident and almost went desperate finding how to disable it

Answer (score 1):

Add/remove a caret: `Alt + Shift + Mouse Click`

Remove all carets: `Esc`

Answer (score 0):

As for now(2018.9), you just:

- Press middle mouse key to create a four-rows-high caret
- Type what you want

Or,

- Create the first line,
- Press the "Duplicate entire line" key combination to create a new, identical line.

By the way, I think "multiple caret" should be like carets enabling me to edit different locations which are not necessarily vertically aligned. In Sublime Text you can press Ctrl and click. And in IntelliJ you can only "Clone caret up/down", that is to say, they are vertically aligned, which is not flexible.

Comment: `IntelliJ you can only "Clone caret up/down"` -- Not sure if this was correct in 2018, but it's not correct as of 2020. It's "Add or remove caret" in the editor keymap.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin [Actionable](https://github.com/MohammadMD1383/Actionable) - [JB Marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17962-actionable) that has a variety of good features that the IDE doesn't have!

Check it out. The action you need here is `Duplicate Line And Insert Contents` or if you have your filed names copied to clipboard, then `Duplicate Line and Paste Contents from Clipboard`

*Actions:*

[image]

*The class: (note where the caret is placed)*

[image]

*Execute the first action that I said:*

[image]

*Press OK:*

[image]